# sql server duplicated result while getting data from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, join

Hi i have a small problem with SQL SERVER .
an building a Purchase and stokes system i want to retrieve data from 3 Tables:-

[Tables Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfrRT.png)

Query:

```
SELECT Tbl_Products.Product_Name, Tbl_PurchaseDetails.BuyPrice, Tbl_PurchaseDetails.AllPieceBoxes, Tbl_PurchaseDetails.TotalPrice, Tbl_PurchaseHeader.purchaseOrder 
FROM Tbl_Products 
INNER JOIN Tbl_PurchaseHeader  ON Tbl_Products.Product_ID = Tbl_PurchaseHeader.ProductId 
INNER JOIN Tbl_PurchaseDetails ON Tbl_PurchaseHeader.purchaseOrder = Tbl_PurchaseDetails.PurchaseOrder
```

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G767c.png)

```
Product_Name          BuyPrice  AllPieceBoxes  TotalPrice  purchaseOrder
--------------------  --------  -------------  ----------  -------------
Dell Alien-Ware       2500.000  5              12500.000   1
KINGSTON-Desktop 8GB  2500.000  5              12500.000   1
Dell Alien-Ware       95.00     10             950.000     1
KINGSTON-Desktop 8GB  95.00     10             950.000     1
```

Comment: Please post your query - the picture is missing the entire JOIN clause.

Comment: @TonyRogerson this is the query:
SELECT        Tbl_Products.Product_Name, Tbl_PurchaseDetails.BuyPrice, Tbl_PurchaseDetails.AllPieceBoxes, Tbl_PurchaseDetails.TotalPrice, 
                         Tbl_PurchaseHeader.purchaseOrder
FROM            Tbl_Products INNER JOIN
                         Tbl_PurchaseHeader ON Tbl_Products.Product_ID = Tbl_PurchaseHeader.ProductId INNER JOIN
                         Tbl_PurchaseDetails ON Tbl_PurchaseHeader.purchaseOrder = Tbl_PurchaseDetails.PurchaseOrder

Comment: @MarcB i posted the question and i think if u don't know the answer so keep quiet

Comment: @MarcB As you can see this is their first post and they aren't familiar with expectations on this site. If the goal is quality questions then isn't it in our best interest to constructively contribute to that process? How about linking to a meta post that outlines how to ask a good question? Let's try to act like a senior member of the community who has achieved 244k reputation.

Comment: @NezarAlazzabi Can you explain what you want to accomplish a little bit better. From your question, it's not clear to me what the goal of your query is.  Also providing the sample data in the tables will help others understand the query results better. 

It's hard to tell with the information provided, but to me it looks like the `Tbl_PurchaseDetails` table also needs a `Product_ID` column, and then the query needs to join that table 'ON Tbl_PurchaseHeader.purchaseOrder = Tbl_PurchaseDetails.PurchaseOrder AND Tbl_Products.Product_ID=Tbl_PurchaseDetails.Product_ID`

Comment: Here is a link to the "[How to ask a good question]"(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" that @TheMuffinMan mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Given the join below I think you have multiple rows for a given Product_ID in Tbl_PurchaseHeader which you then join with tbl_PurchaseDetails. For example if there are two rows in Tbl_PurchaseHeader with Product_ID of 1 then you will join with Tbl_PurchaseDetails twice so 1 Tbl_Products gives 2 Tbl_PurchaseHeader's which if there are multiple (say 3) rows in Tbl_PurchaseDetails then you'll get an additional 2 x 3 so 6 rows.

```
FROM Tbl_Products 
    INNER JOIN Tbl_PurchaseHeader ON Tbl_Products.Product_ID = Tbl_PurchaseHeader.ProductId 
    INNER JOIN Tbl_PurchaseDetails ON Tbl_PurchaseHeader.purchaseOrder = Tbl_PurchaseDetails.PurchaseOrder
```

Check out your data, do a singleton SELECT against each table and track the data through to see how many rows come back for a) Product_ID and then for PurchaseOrder.